# X1, X2, X4 encoding for encoders in Arduino

Tags: encoding, arduino, encoder

So, I'm coding for an encoder in Arduino and I'm not sure what type of encoding I'm using in my code. I'm also curious how X1, X2 and X4 encoding would look like in the arduino code. Below is the code that I used.

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    #define outputA 5 //channel A
    #define outputB 6 //channel B
    int counter = 0;
    int degree = 0;
    int aState;
    int aLastState;
    encoderPPR = 2048 //real ppr*2

    void setup() {
      pinMode (outputA, INPUT_PULLUP);
      pinMode (outputB, INPUT_PULLUP);

      Serial.begin(9600);
      //Reads the initial state of the outputA
      aLastState = digitalRead(outputA);
    }

    void loop(){
      aState = digitalRead(outputA); //reads the 'current' state of the outputA
      if (aState != aLastState) {                 //if there's a shift (perubahan)
      if (digitalRead(outputB) != aState) {
         counter ++;
      } else {
         counter --;
      }
     if (counter > encoderPPR or counter < -encoderPPR)
      {
        counter = 0;
      }
     }
    derajat = counter * 360 / encoderPPR;
    aLastState = aState;
}

    }
```

This is the code that I used. Is the encoding used in the code above X2 or X4 because I'm not sure myself. Thank you.

Comment: That's X2.  It's only reacting to one pin, the A pin, and when it changes it checks the state of the B pin to see which direction.  To get X1 you would change so that it not only checks for a change of state on the A pin, but also that the state was HIGH or LOW (pick one).  To make it X4 you need to replicate that code for the B pin so that it also reacts when the B pin changes state and checks the A pin.

Comment: I see, thank you! @Delta_G!